# How to create a column/div that overlaps certain other divs to have a sticky sidebar but still keep the background color of the other divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website with Angular and have to make a sticky box at the right side. The sticky box will stay sticky inside it's own div. However, i need this div to be overlapping the actual content, because the background colors need to be visible behind this sticky box.

I'm adding a picture to make it clearer.

the black parts are divs that should not be overlapped by the sticky, the red/pink divs are the content, each div has a different color. i need the sticky box to be at the green box.

the contents inside the red/pink parts all have a width of 65%, so the sticky box won't overlap the actual content.

https://i.gyazo.com/734f1e00797ae782d71046dfceba6f78.png

how can i achieve this?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: i've tried wrapping each column in a div with a width of 65%/35% and float: left;, but that results in the right column having no background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```css
.container
{
  position: relative; /*I use it to set .sidebar top and right property relative to this container*/
}
.sidebar
{
  height: 150px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(200,255,200,0.4);
  position: absolute; /*make it overlap*/
  right: 0; /*align to right*/
  top: 70px; /*your black div height*/
  z-index: 10;  
}
.row
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.color1
{
  background-color: black;
  height: 70px;
}
.color2
{
  background-color: red;
}
.color3
{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="row color1"></div>
  <div class="row color2"></div>
  <div class="row color3"></div>
  <div class="row color2"></div>
  <div class="row color1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use fixed `height` in your sidebar you can set `position: absolute` for all divs and use `z-index` property to overlap black divs on sidebar

Comment: i've added my %-values and this seems to work perfectly fine, thank you very much!